# Putty Monokai Color Scheme manually

Tags: bash, putty

I would like to use the [Monokai](https://github.com/AlexAkulov/putty-color-themes/blob/master/27.%20Monokai%20Soda.reg) color scheme in PuTTY. However, I don't have administrator privileges so I cant use the reg file to import the scheme. The only way I can is manually change the colors at Change Settings > Window > Colors.
[image: this color]
I'm looking for a correspondence table with in RGB colors and PuTTY color names as bellow:

- Default Foreground
- Default Bold Foreground
- Default Background
- Default Bold Background
- Cursor Text
- Cursor Colour
- ANSI Black
- ANSI Black Bold
- ANSI Red
- ANSI Red Bold
- ANSI Green
- ANSI Green Bold
- ANSI Yellow
- ANSI Yellow Bold
- ANSI Blue
- ANSI Blue Bold
- ANSI Magenta
- ANSI Magenta Bold
- ANSI Cyan
- ANSI Cyan Bold
- ANSI White
- ANSI White Bold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`Colour0` in the .reg file corresponds to the first color listed under *Window -> Colours -> Select a color to adjust* in PuTTY, `Colour21` corresponds to the last color in the list.

#### Long Answer

In PuTTY load the session you would like to edit.  Go to *Window -> Colours and under -> Select a color to adjust* use the following RGB values for each color:

- Default Foreground: 196,197,181
- Default Bold Foreground: 196,197,181
- Default Background: 26,26,26
- Default Bold Background: 26,26,26
- Cursor Text: 246,247,236
- Cursor Colour: 196,197,181
- ANSI Black: 26,26,26
- ANSI Black Bold: 98,94,76
- ANSI Red: 244,0,95
- ANSI Red Bold: 244,0,95
- ANSI Green: 152,224,36
- ANSI Green Bold: 152,224,36
- ANSI Yellow: 250,132,25
- ANSI Yellow Bold: 224,213,97
- ANSI Blue: 157,101,255
- ANSI Blue Bold: 157,101,255
- ANSI Magenta: 244,0,95
- ANSI Magenta Bold: 244,0,95
- ANSI Cyan: 88,209,235
- ANSI Cyan Bold: 88,209,235
- ANSI White: 196,197,181
- ANSI White Bold: 246,246,239

#### Pretty PuTTY

Check out [Pretty PuTTY](https://github.com/jacektrocinski/pretty-putty) for other useful settings such as:

- 256 color support
- UTF-8 character support
- Consolas 12pt ClearType font
- Linux style copy-and-pasting (middle click to paste)
- Scrollback buffer set to 2000 lines
- Seconds between keepalives set to 59
- Mouse pointer hides while typing
- Initial window size set to 80x40